# how should i separate firebase projects?

Tags: firebase

my question is, should I separate firebase app and function and hosting projects?

put it in different folders like:

- app
- hosting
- functions

or put it in the same folder and thats it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea of folder is to separate the resources and create an structure with different organizational accesses, as is mentioned in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/folders-a-powerful-tool-to-manage-cloud-resources?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%2BClPlBl%2B(Cloud%2BPlatform%2BBlog))

If your projects and their resources are not interconnected using folders could be useful to quickly identify a project category and you can create some sub folders with the stage of your projects.

For example

```
app
  -- DEV
  -- PROD
  -- Q&A
```

For more information about folder please check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy)